# I want to pass html form values to href tag on button

Tags: javascript, html, shopify, liquid

I am currently working on a Shopify store.

I want to add a button that when clicked opens a whatsapp chat with the current info on the product that the customer is watching.

However there is a  form on the product page that gets filled by the customer, and I want to pass those values to the link that opens the chats.

Here's what I have right now, this code includes liquid code and html:

```
<form action="https://wa.me/50258437780?text=¡Hola!%20estoy%20interesado%20en%20el%20siguiente%20mueble:%20{{product.title}}%20,%20{{current_variant.title}}">
  <label for="fname">Código tela:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="tela" value="" name="fname"><br>
  <label for="lname">Código Acabado:</label><br>
  <input type="text" id="acabado" name="fname"><br>
  <a class="button" href="https://wa.me/50258437780?text=¡Hola!%20estoy%20interesado%20en%20el%20siguiente%20mueble:%20{{product.title}}%20,%20{{current_variant.title}}+document.getElementById('tela').value">COTIZAR</a> <br>
</form>
```

Comment: Is there any error on console? You may try to add a function and pass parameters to it when button is clicked. Than call window.location (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) to redirect to whatsapp chat

Answer (score 0):

I used javascript to solve it, captured the elements by ID and then appended them using concat(), also I assigned the link value to a variable in order to concatenate it